# How to migrate a model in gorm?

Tags: go, go-gorm

I am a beginner golang developer I use GORM package to connect to DB.
How to migration and a model like following in GORM:

```
type Product struct {
    ID         int64
    Name       string
    created_at  int64
    updated_at  int64
}
```

Comment: Take a look at this, but please add more details to your question.
https://github.com/golang-migrate/migrate
http://gorm.io/docs/migration.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can migrate to your database with following command

```
db.AutoMigrate(&Product{})
```

This command migrates if product model does not exist in database

This is usually used as a CREATE statement

you can also see here to more information.
[GORM migration document](http://gorm.io/docs/migration.html)